# how to get length of part of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript I have an array of objects "city". Example:

```
var city = {name:'Kortenberg',lat:50.8884334,longcoord:4.5440302,province:'vb',group:'1492683180968819'};
var data = [city];

city = {name:'Braine',lat:50.8884334,longcoord:4.5440302,province:'wb',group:'Freecycle.BrainelAlleud'};
data.push(city);
```

to get the length of the array, I just do `data.length` . But is it possible to get the length of the array for all objects who has "wb" as province?

Comment: why not just write a for loop ? What's the problem ?

Comment: What Denys says, you are required to iterate over this data and I don't believe there are languages that do this automagically for you unless you store it in a database with indexes, then you can count this.

Comment: What about `data.filter(function (item) { return item.province === 'wb'; }).length`?

Answer (score 0):

```
data.filter(function (item) { return item.province === 'wb'; }).length
```

has done the trick. Thanks limelights